# Trouble with CSS box-shadow while using JQuery to highlight elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have a simple JQuery element selector - as you'd expect, moving in and out of elements does some highlighting. It works, but I'm running into 2 issues that I'd love some help with please (I'm sure a CSS whizz will solve this in seconds!!):

1) adjacent elements sometimes mask the highlighting of their neighbours (see `DIV` 1 in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FusrG/2/) - I'd like to have the red shadow appear on all FOUR sides of `DIV` 1, rather than only on those that don't touch a neighbouring `DIV` - I also tried adding a `z-index` but it doesn't solve it)

2) when an element contains an anchor link that has text which word wraps onto more than one line each line of text is highlighted - ideally I'd like the whole link to be highlighted (e.g. see `DIV` 4 in the same [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FusrG/2/) - hover over the link that wraps over 3 lines - rather than having 3 red shadow boxes, can I get 1 shadow box around the whole link?

**NOTES:**
I'm using this code on top of a variety of 3rd party web pages, so I can not change/edit the HTML in a scalable way

**EDIT:**

Thanks to those who answered below - your solutions worked on my fiddle demo - I've now taken these across into my actual code but I can't get the images to 'come to the front' when I hover over them - many images still only have their hover SHADOW appearing on less than 4 sides - my code is this (but needs php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <style>
        img:hover{
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 17px 10px green;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 17px 10px green;
            box-shadow: 0 0 17px 10px green;
            z-index:5555555555;
            position:relative;
        }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php 
    echo'<div>';
             $url = 'http://www.guardian.co.uk';
             $data = file_get_contents($url);
             echo $data;
    echo'</div>';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1 - you are only seeing the border on three sides because the bottom edge is under the second box. Pop it to the front like this - this actually bring any of your sibling divs to the front when hovered

```
div:hover {z-index:5; position:relative;}
```

Question 2 - set the link to

```
display:block;
```

see my update to your fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/FusrG/9/

Comment: Charles - thanks for your help on this - I've taken some of this into my code - see my edit above in the orginal question - I still can't get the images to come to the front in that (even though it worked in the fiddle example) - any idea where I'm going wrong? (thanks)

Comment: Steve - you are trying to apply the z-index to the img - apply it to the containing div instead. Also, the shadow is on all four sides, but the second box is overlaying it; once you can pop the element to the front, you will see the shadow all around it - hth

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first, why not just use the `:hover` pseudo-selector in CSS?

```
div:hover, a:hover
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 17px 10px #f51f4c;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 17px 10px #f51f4c;
  box-shadow: 0 0 17px 10px #f51f4c !important;
}​
```

Instead of using JS to do something that CSS has built in?

You'll have to give the `.top` div a position and z-index for it to display as you wish, and add `display: inline-block;` to the anchor for it to wrap around the link as you expected.

```
.sky a
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/FusrG/7/

Using CSS hover to fix the shadow: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/FusrG/11/

Comment: Your example now has the shadow z-index issue on the second div instead.

Comment: @kyle-sevenoaks - please see my edit to the original question above - I've tried but can't get the 'bring to front' piece working on my new code - thanks

Comment: We need to see the output HTML from the browser, we have no idea what is inside that PHP call.

Comment: Kyle, it's nothing clever - it just loads the homepage of that website  in the container div on my page and allows my css to 'hover' over its elements so I can select an image from that page.

Comment: @Steve - It will still be useful, as we can make sure that you're not generating something with a syntax error or other issue that would keep the solution from working.